# clicking a NSToolbarItem in XCTest UI Testing

Tags: xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm writing UI Tests for a document-based macOS app.

**In a UI Test, how can I click on an NSToolbarTiem in a localization friendly way?**

Recording doesn't record anything when I click on one.

`NSToolbarItem` doesn't seem to have an `accessibilityIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect elements tree `print(app.debugDescription)`

Find your element and click with something like `app.toolbars["brushes"].firstMatch.click()`

If `accessibilityIdentifier` and `label` are missing, add them in application code or storyboard.